# ActiveAdmin - Custom action with reusing the show form

Tags: activeadmin

I am creating a custom action that serve as show view with ActiveAdmin, is there any helper I can reused on the partial so I can reuse the ActiveAdmin show view template.

I reckons with show action, you could customise the arrangement with attributes_tables, is there something similar I could reuse for the view?

```
show do |ad|
  attributes_table do
    row :title
  end
end
```

Here's my custom action:

```
member_action :read do
    @app = App.find(params[:id])
    #Rendering Partial
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use partials in both views, with a bit of a hack:

`app/admin/apps.rb`

```
ActiveAdmin.register App do
  show do
    @app = App.find(params[:id])
    render "show", context: self
  end

  member_action :read do
    @app = App.find(params[:id])
  end 
end
```

`app/views/admin/apps/_show.builder`

```
context.instance_eval do
  div do
    panel "Address" do
      attributes_table_for @address do
        row :address_line_1
      end
    end
    active_admin_comments_for @address
  end
end
```

`app/views/admin/apps/read.builder`

```
render "show", context: self
```

**Edit:** Made it work!

**Edit 2:** Made comments work!

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried your solution, but it come out error of "undefined method `attributes_table' for". I think there's typo with you render "show", context: self as well.

Comment: Ah, right. I guess it should read "attributes_table_for". No typo on render though :) Try again with my updated answer.

Comment: I tried, but it throws this error "undefined method `attributes_table_for' for" this time.

Comment: Ok, I actually spent some time to try it myself, I have updated my answer with a working one. Even more of a hack that I first thought...